# Setting set of text values for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, cross-join

I am working in SQL server and have two tables in my database, I am attaching their sample screenshots below:

Table 1:[table_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Owo.png)

And the second table is as shown in the image below:

Table 2:[table_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQYyt.png)

I am trying to assign all the Korean language values from table_1 which are in Action_Item_in_Korean column to each value in the Asset_No column so my output should look like as shown below:

Output:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C97gE.png)

Each Asset_No should repeat 8 times because there are 8 values in table_1 that need to be updated. , I know that simple update query is not enough to display the output as I need, searched alot but so far unable to design a solution for this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Sample data should really be provided as DDL and DML statements, but any data should at least be supplied as either a markdown table or well formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: Noted, but these table had korean language symbols which I tried copy here but could not get the desired formatting

Comment: @SteveSmith The language of the text appears to be irrelevant. Do you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged "cross join" and that seems like it satisfies your goal. A simple example is:

```
select <columns you desire> 
from dbo.[table 1] as t1 cross join dbo.[table 2] as t2
order by ...
;
```

Comment: thank you this solved my problem and got the desired results.